# startUpdatingLocation in init

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, geolocation, core-location

My question is simple:
Is it OK to is these:

```objc
manager.delegate = self;
[manager startUpdatingLocation];
return self;
```

as the last lines of an -init method?

By that point the object should be constructed, however I have a bad feeling about this.

Also relevant - if it's not OK to do this, should I postpone the execution of `-startUpdatingLocation` and with what amount of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely fine. Init is a valid method in which to do this.

The only time you need to delay is when you need to use something that gets initalised further on in the execution of the code. e.g. to make changes to the View you should do that in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidLoad` as the view won't be properly set up in the init method.

In this example however you're not using anything that gets set up in your object later down the line, so its fine to use the init method.

Always remember to run `[super init]` first though so that the object is set up properly.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok.

as in normal case you do the same. i.e

- You initilize it
- Set the delegate
- Then start updating location.

Same thing you are doing here.